# iOS App without storing username on device

Tags: ios, security, authentication

I would like to develop an iOS app that does some authentication without storing username and password on the device. Is there a way to do this ?

Based on what I read so far there is documentation to store the username and password in keychain. But that would mean storing the username / password on the device ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665289/how-to-authenticate-a-mobile-app-without-username-and-password?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use the free parse service to create a database with the built in user and password properties of a PFObject. Great tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/19341/how-to-easily-create-a-web-backend-for-your-apps-with-parse